# AWS S3 Lifecycle

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been exploring AWS S3 Lifecycle techniques and found the best way to delete S3 files > 60 days old is to configure this through the GUI.

However, I'm not wanting to delete ALL files greater than 60 days. For example, I'd like to at least keep all HTML files inside the bucket that are greater than 60 days.

I've found that a prefix can be entered to limit the scope of the lifecycle to a specific file; however, this requires me to enter ALL files EXCEPT HTMLs. We have hundreds of files, so this will take forever.

I was wondering if anyone knew of an easier way? For example, I would like to just exclude all `*.html` from the lifecycle.

[image: Lifecycle]

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to exclude object from rules.
You can rearrange object in your bucket so rule can be applied to objects in specified prefix ("folder").